# Jquery UI datepicker setdate not working for one datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui

I have 2 datepickers one for dateend and another for datestart.
I have a button in the html when you click it a dialog-form is going to appear.
then a ask data and populate the elements in the modal form. the modal form has date end and date start. but it seems the datestart is the only one populated. pls help. i really dont know what is wrong, stuck for more than 4days

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "drop", //explode
        hide: "clip",
        autoResize: true,
        height: '500',
        width: 'auto',
        draggable: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false
    });
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function () {
        var buttonHolder = $('input[type="button"]');
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
        $("#timeStart").timepicker({});
        $("#dateStart").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            dateFormat: "yy/mm/d",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            minDate: new Date(), // min date should be date of today or the date which he set as startdate
            onClose: function () { //selectedDate should be value. i think. problem lies in the selected.
                $("#dateEnd").datepicker("option", "minDate", $(this).val());
            }
        });
        $("#dateEnd").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            dateFormat: "yy/mm/d",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onClose: function () {
                $("#dateStart").datepicker("option", "maxDate", $(this).val()); //$(this).val()
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('ajax/getEventOfModal'); ?>",
            data: {
                id: $(this).attr('id'),
                username: "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('email'); ?>"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#event_id").attr('value', buttonHolder.attr('id'));
                $("#event_name").attr('value', data['name']);
                $("#event_loc").text(data['loc']);
                $("#event_desc").text(data['desc']);
                $("#timeStart").timepicker('setTime', data['timeStart']);
                var queryDate = data['dateStart'],
                    dateParts = queryDate.match(/(\d+)/g)
                    realDate = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[2]); // months are 0-based!
                $('#dateStart').datepicker('setDate', realDate);
                var queryDate2 = data['dateEnd'],
                    dateParts2 = queryDate2.match(/(\d+)/g)
                    realDate2 = new Date(dateParts2[0], dateParts2[1] - 1, dateParts2[2]); // months are 0-based!
                $('#dateEnd').datepicker('setDate', realDate2);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What's the value of `data`?

Comment: im using codeigniter and
`code`
$struct = array(
'name' => $row->event_name, 
'username' => $row->username, 
'loc' => $row->location, 
'desc' => $row->description, 
'timeStart' => $row->time_start, 
'dateStart' => $row->date_start, 
'dateEnd' => $row->date_end
);
echo json_encode($struct);

Comment: the thing is, it works for datestart. but why not for dateend

Comment: Maybe there's some difference in how they show up in the JSON. Since you haven't shown it as asked, I can't tell.

Comment: i tried to alert display it using alert it gives me "[object Object]"
if i display data['dateEnd'] it gives me a date format of "YYYY-MM-DD"
i do not know how to display all the elements in data at once

Comment: i displayed all data in alert by accessing data[''] one by one. the format of dateStart and dateEnd is just the same

Comment: Use `console.log(data)` rather than `alert(data)`.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and check the value of `realDate2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `defaultdate` from the jquery datepicker.